# Imprimir salto de linea desde return e invertir orden impresión de una lista

Tags: java

tengo 2 problemas.
Necesito que cuando se ejecute la linea de "return", tambien me deje una linea en blanco por debajo.

y la otra duda, es como hacer que mi String[] (creo que es un array), se imprima al revez. De momento se me imprime desde el ultimo al primer item.

````
    // guardo a los ingredientes en un array
    String[] arreglo_Ingredientes; // creo array
    arreglo_Ingredientes = new String[this.getIngredientes().size()]; // inicializo el array
    this.getIngredientes().toArray(arreglo_Ingredientes); // guardo la lista de ingredientes en el arreglo
    int largo = this.getIngredientes().size(); // guardo el largo de la lista
    int cont = 0; // contador
    String aux = null; // string que va a guardar el ultimo ingrediente

    if (this.isCerrada() == false) {
      // esta abierta
      System.out.println("Receta " + this.getNombre() + " (incompleta)");
      System.out.println("Ingredientes: " );
      for (String a : arreglo_Ingredientes) {
        cont++;
        if (cont < largo) {
          System.out.println(a);
        } else {
          aux = a;
        }
      }
      return aux;
    } else {
      // esta cerrada
      System.out.println("Receta " + this.getNombre() + " (completa)");
      System.out.println("Ingredientes: " );
      for (String a : arreglo_Ingredientes) {
        cont++;
        if (cont < largo) {
          System.out.println(a);
        } else {
          aux = a;
        }
      }
      return aux;
    }
  }```
````

Comment: podrias agregar un salto de linea de esta manera `aux=a+"\n";` con respecto a la impresion habria que ver como estas guardando los datos en la lista ya  que tu array mantiene el orden en que estos fueron guardados en dicha lista

Comment: En cuanto al salto de linea, muchas gracias, eso fue la solucion al problema.
En cuanto a lo otro, los datos en la lista son cargados a medida que son mandados a cargar. (utilice el metodo .add() )

Comment: Ahora que lo pienzo, quizas pueda solucionar mi problema recorriendo la lista con el for, en orden inverso. Pero como se hace eso? (ni si quiera se si es posible)

Comment: podrías probar dándole vuelta a la lista antes de pasarlo al array de esta manera `Collections.reverse(this.getIngredientes());` si resuleve tu problema significa que estas agregando los datos a la lista de manera decreciente

Comment: Me da un error que no termino de entender bien, pero creo que tiene que ver con que mi lista de ingredientes es de tipo "Set" y no una lista.
Adjunto el error:
The method reverse(List<?>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Set<String>)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Toda lista es recorrible desde su ultimo item al primero usando un for y entrando por indice ;). Tu metodo no deberia devolver un salto de linea.. del salto de linea deberia ocuparse quien imprime esa cadena que fue devuelta. esto "this.isCerrada() == false" se puede reemplazar por "!this.isCerrada()".. si la variable es booleana, compararlo con algo booleano no tiene sentido ;)....

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los comentarios que recibí pude solucionar mi problema (no de la mejor forma, pero al menos hace lo que necesito que haga).

Les dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve.

````
    // guardo a los ingredientes en un array
    String[] arreglo_Ingredientes; // creo array
    arreglo_Ingredientes = new String[this.getIngredientes().size()]; // inicializo el array
    this.getIngredientes().toArray(arreglo_Ingredientes); // guardo la lista de ingredientes en el arreglo
    int largo = this.getIngredientes().size(); // guardo el largo de la lista
    int cont = 0; // contador
    String aux = null; // string que va a guardar el ultimo ingrediente
    List<String> arreglo_Invertido = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arreglo_Ingredientes));
    Collections.reverse(arreglo_Invertido);
      
    if (this.isCerrada() == false) {
      // esta abierta
      System.out.println("Receta " + this.getNombre() + " (incompleta)");
      System.out.println("Ingredientes: " );
      for (String a : arreglo_Invertido) {
        cont++;
        if (cont < largo) {
          System.out.println(a);
        } else {
          aux = a + "\n";
        }
      }
      return aux;
    } else {
      // esta cerrada
      System.out.println("Receta " + this.getNombre() + " (completa)");
      System.out.println("Ingredientes: " );
      for (String a : arreglo_Invertido) {
        cont++;
        if (cont < largo) {
          System.out.println(a);
        } else {
          aux = a + "\n";
        }
      }
      return aux ;
    }
  } ```
````